# iPhone Regular Expression With Pattern to Extract URL of Image

Tags: iphone, regex, xcode, uiimage

I parse an RSS feed and am attempting to get the URL to the image in the feed that is located in the content:encoded item of the RSS.  There are multiple HREFs in this section of text, and the regex with pattern I have been using just pulls out the first URL.  I found this pattern online, and am not for sure how I could change it to what I need.  Any thoughts?

```
NSString *thearticleImage = entry.articleImage;
    NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
    NSString *someString = thearticleImage;
    NSString *oneurl = [someString substringWithRange:[expression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn Regular Expressions if you want to alter the regex pattern.  Have a look at:[Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html/).

What have you tried so far?